# React Native - How to get camera roll thumbnails instead of full size images

Tags: react-native

I am trying to get images from my test devices camera roll to render as thumbnails. I have successfully fetched the images from the camera roll and displayed them within a series of Image elements in a list view but they take a really long time to load in. Also, I read in the React Native docs that the Image element will pick the correct image size for the space it will render into.

This is from the docs.

> iOS saves multiple sizes for the same image in your Camera Roll, it is very important to pick the one that's as close as possible for performance reasons. You wouldn't want to use the full quality 3264x2448 image as source when displaying a 200x200 thumbnail. If there's an exact match, React Native will pick it, otherwise it's going to use the first one that's at least 50% bigger in order to avoid blur when resizing from a close size. All of this is done by default so you don't have to worry about writing the tedious (and error prone) code to do it yourself. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#best-camera-roll-image

The code I'm using to read the images is super simple.

```
    CameraRoll.getPhotos({
        first: 21,
        assetType: 'Photos'
    }, (data) => {
        console.log(data);
        var images = data.edges.map((asset) => {
            return {
                uri: asset.node.image.uri
            };
        });

        this.setState({
            images: this.state.images.cloneWithRows(images)
        });
    }, () => {
        this.setState({
            retrievePhotoError: messages.errors.retrievePhotos
        });
    });
```

And then to render it I have these functions.

```
renderImage(image) {
    return <Image resizeMode="cover" source={{uri: image.uri}} style={[{
        height: imageDimensions, // imageDimensions == 93.5
        width: imageDimensions
    }, componentStyles.thumbnails]}/>;
},

render() {
    <ListView
        automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
        contentContainerStyle={componentStyles.row}
        dataSource={this.state.images}
        renderRow={this.renderImage}
    />
}
```

What am I missing here? I'm going crazy!!!

Comment: do you come out with javascript solution yet?

Comment: This demo may help for what you are looking for : https://github.com/logisticinfotech/react-native-resize-image

Answer (score 2):

OK, it is possible but you'll have to put your hands in the Objective-C party of react-native.

You can check [this](https://medium.com/@scottdixon/react-native-posting-uploading-ios-camera-roll-images-to-a-server-6c74766154cd#.sk8non326).

You'll have to modify the RCTCameraRollManager.m file.

You'll have to add these lines :

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:uri];

[library assetForURL:url resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {

  // Create an ALAssetRepresentation object using our asset
  // and turn it into a bitmap using the CGImageRef opaque type.
  CGImageRef imageRef = [asset thumbnail];
  CGSize dimensions = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef].size;

  // Create UIImageJPEGRepresentation from CGImageRef
  NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef], 0.1);
```

before the `[assets addObject:@{...}]` method and add :

```
} failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
  NSLog(@"that didn't work %@", error);
}];
```

after the `[assets addObject:@{...}]` method.

You can also add the prop `@"base64": base64Encoded` in the `[assets addObject:@{` method.

Check the link, you have the "new file" that gives you the thumbnail (125 x 125 size).

Comment: This is solution for iOS, do you have similar for android?

Answer (score 0):

I also struggled to find the solution. Apparently, [react-native-image-resizer](https://github.com/bamlab/react-native-image-resizer)

solves this.
Here is how I used it:

```
import ImageResizer from 'react-native-image-resizer';

async getPhotos(){
    await CameraRoll.getPhotos({
        first: 10 ,
        assetType: 'Photos'
    })
    .then(r => {
        this.setState({ photos:r.edges, endCursorPhotos:r.page_info.end_cursor }) 
        let resizePromiseArray = []
        for(let i=0; i<r.edges.length; i++){
            resizePromiseArray.push(ImageResizer.createResizedImage(r.edges[i].node.image.uri , 300, 500, 'JPEG', 100))
        }
        return Promise.all(resizePromiseArray)
    })
    .then(newUris=>{
        // console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.photos,null,4))
        let newPhotos = this.state.photos.map((photo,i) => {
            photo.node.image['optiUri'] = newUris[i]
            return photo
        })
        this.setState({ photos:newPhotos })
    })
    .catch(err =>{
        console.log(err)
    })
}
```

I'm adding the thumbnail to the image object to have an option to use either as need be. 
You can resize just one image. 
 
It's not incredibly fast so, it's better to do it at componentDidMount.
An even better approach is to use it in a these photos in a Modal while the parent component will load and save photos to state before the user accesses them